# Prove that $P_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^n \delta_{X_i(\omega)}$ converges weakly almost surely to $P_{X_0}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am supposed to prove that given a sequence of independent, equally distributed random variables $X_i \in \mathcal{L}^1$, on a probability space $\{\Omega,  \mathcal{A}, P\}$ 
the  sequence $P_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^n \delta_{X_i(\omega)}$
converges weakly almost surely to $P_{X_0}$ (with $\omega \in \Omega$)
My attempt: 
Let $f \in C_b \; \omega \in \Omega$
Set  $$Y_i = f \circ X_i$$
This sequence is also independent and equally distributed

$\Rightarrow$ We can use the law of large numbers
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^n Y_i \rightarrow \int_{\Omega} Y_0 dP = \int_{\Omega} f \circ X_0 dP = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f d_{P_{X_0}}$$ almost surely
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f dP_n = \sum_{i=0}^n f(X_i(w)) \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^n Y_i(\omega)$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \int_{\mathbb{R}} f dP_n = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f d_{P_{X_0}}$$ almost surely.

But this is not actually the result we want, because this just shows that given an $f$ the sequence of integrals almost surely converges. But I need to show that if it converges for one $f$ that it also converges for all other $f \in C_b$ and I dont know how to do that (especially because there are uncountably many such f) 
Can someone maybe give me a tip or help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key point here is that there exists a sequence $(f_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ of functions satisfying the following: $\mu_n\to \mu$ weakly if and only if for each $k$, $\int f_kd\mu_n\to\int f_kd\mu$.

Pick $\Omega_k$ of probability one such that $\int f_k dP_{n,\omega}$ converges for each $\omega\in \Omega$ and then consider the intersection of the sets $\Omega_k$.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand. Are you saying it's enough to show the convergence for a countable sequence of function In $C_B$ instead of for all bounded continuous functions? If so, that's not something that's part of my course.

Comment: You can take a set of functions that is dense in the space of continuous functions with compact support. Indeed, the point is that you have a convergence determining class of functions and you do not need to show the convergence of $\int fd\mu_n$ for each $f$ but only for the $ff$'s in this class. Which material have you covered? Portmanteau theorem?

Comment: Ah thank you. Yes indeed we have covered this.  The contious functions with compact support are seperable while the bounded ones are not.

Comment: You are welcome!